# Calculating completed percentage of a jigsaw puzzle

Tags: problem-solving, puzzle

At first I thought the solution for this problem was simple…maybe to you it will be, but it evades me at present.

I need to figure out how to calculate the completed percentage of a jigsaw puzzle. Here are some examples:

Say I have 25 (5 x 5) piece jigsaw puzzle. If I calculated it correctly, that would be 40 potential individual piece matches.

[image]

Now if I just figure how many connections have taken place and divide that by the full number, that *should* give me my percentage, right? Wrong—at least perceptually speaking the issue seems to be a little more complex than that.

Here's why. Take a look at this 4 piece puzzle being solved.

[image]

I can offer more complicated examples if needed (I realized that 4 pieces is overly simplistic).

I have been racking my brain but I don't seem to be coming up with a solution that addresses all of these issues.

Comment: To me, it seems your problem is that you haven't specified an **actual** metric.  Intuition can only go so far, and when it's something 'perceptual', then it makes sense that it may not actually be consistent

Comment: The answer/solution must be perceptually correct because the goal is to analyze the progress of a jigsaw puzzle and determine how much is completed. To a real person, you wouldn't count two halves of the puzzle that are fully assembled as having any more than one match left, though technically speaking, there are two.

Comment: Nevertheless, 'perceptually correct' must be defined.  I do not mean to say that there is no solution that can make what is 'perceptual' rigorous, but only that what is considered perceptual must be rigorously defined before any real progress can be made.

Comment: @daveMac At some point you will have to defer to rigorous values rather than perception.  I think the "perception" in this case is wrong.

Comment: Just a rhetorical question: in the Monty Hall problem, would you say the probability of winning if you switch should be displayed at 1/2, because this is "perceptually" correct?

Answer (score 3):

Think in components instead of connections. Let's define a *move* to be when two components of the puzzle are connected, as in the picture below.

[image: One move]

In a puzzle with $n$ pieces, you start with $n$ components (each piece is a component) and you are finished when there is $1$ component left (the entire puzzle), so the puzzle requires exactly $n-1$ moves. Then your progress will be $\frac{\text{pieces}\,-\,\text{components}}{\text{pieces}\,-\,1}$.

[image: Progress]